# 4 character string combination java

Tags: string, loops, iterator, character, permutation

Good day,

I have to write a program that prints all permutations of the String "abcd" with the following restrictions:

- the strings must always have 4 characters;
- one character can be used more then once in a string;
- "b" must always be followed by "a";
- a string cannot have both "d" and "a"; and
- the program must also print at the end the number of strings printed.

here is the working code i came up with so far.

Now i have to add code for :

- "b" must always be followed by "a";
- a string cannot have both "d" and "a";

Can someone help me with this ?

```
public class Combination2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "abcd";

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
                

                String res = "" + s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(j) + s.charAt(k) + s.charAt(d);
        
                count++;
                System.out.println("" + res);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("There are " + count + " combinations");
}
```

}

Comment: please make an attempt, and then post your code when you run into a roadblock

Answer (score 0):

The simplest place to start would probably be to generate all permutations of the String "abcd" while ignoring the restrictions. Then once you have that figured out try and work on the restrictions.